# C# API query for Alternate key

Tags: c#, api, mapper

I'm trying to do this query: `SELECT * FROM Machine WHERE KlantId = [Id from url]` in c# but its returing only 1 row when it should be 2 rows. I manualy change the input of KlantId in the url. The url looks like this: `https://00.00.00.00:0000/api/Machine/1`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Api output:
[image]

Api Model:

```
[
  {
    "SerienummerId": 1,
    "Serienummer": "10K13321",
    "Bouwjaar": "2020",
    "Urenstand": "10",
    "Locatie": "-23134123, 123123",
    "KlantId": "1"
  },
  {
    "SerienummerId": 2,
    "Serienummer": "25K84314",
    "Bouwjaar": "1998",
    "Urenstand": "5010",
    "Locatie": "-23134123, 123123",
    "KlantId": "1"
  }
]
```

C# MachineRepository

```
public class MachineRepository: IRepository<MachineModel>
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        public MachineRepository(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        
        // Get Service by  id
        public async Task<MachineModel> GetDataById(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Machine.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.KlantId == id);
        }
    }
```

MachineController:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/Machine")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class MachineController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IRepository<MachineModel> _repo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public MachineController(IRepository<MachineModel> repo, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetServiceById(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the comming id ");
        Console.WriteLine(id);

        var model = await _repo.GetDataById(id);
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<MachineDto>(model));
    }
}
```

Comment: In `GetDataById` method for `MachineRepository`, you are using `FirstOrDefaultAsync` which it will query the **first and only one** matched record. You can see the first screenshot, which the translated SQL is with `SELECT TOP 1 ...`.

Comment: Use `.Where` instead. You will want to change the return type to `Task<IEnumerable<MachineModel>>` as well, to actually support returning multiple instances. And, of course, you should be renaming your methods and parameters to be representative of what they are -- finding machines by customer ID is an entirely different operation from selecting one machine by its id, and has nothing to do with "services" or "data" (which is likely boilerplate that was copied without change).

Comment: Could you give me an example how to change it to .Where? @JeroenMostert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirstOrDefaultAsync will return the top 1 record.

Change 1 - In C# MachineRepository, Instead of `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, replace this with `Where` and change the return type to `List`

Change 2 - In MachineController, Map it to `List` DTO

> Note: I assume Machine is having array of records

```
 public class MachineRepository: IRepository<MachineModel>
 {
     private readonly DataContext _context;
     public MachineRepository(DataContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
     }
        
     // Get Service by  id
     public async Task<List<MachineModel>> GetDataById(int id) //change the return type to LIST
     {
         return await _context.Machine.Where(x => x.KlantId == id).ToListAsync();
      }
 }


[ApiController]
[Route("api/Machine")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class MachineController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IRepository<MachineModel> _repo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public MachineController(IRepository<MachineModel> repo, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetServiceById(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the comming id ");
        Console.WriteLine(id);

        var model = await _repo.GetDataById(id);
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<MachineDto>>(model)); //Map to List
    }
}
```